# Artifactory Jenkins plugin: Enable manual build promotion for pipeline job

Tags: artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use build promotion without release staging. Our workflow is: we publish every successful build as release (not snapshot) artifact and deploy it to our staging environment.

Days later, we would decide whether or not to deploy these artifacts in production, depending of their content. I'd like to promote the selected builds to a different repository to exclude them from build retention.

With freestyle jobs with the artifactory plugin, I can simply enable "**Allow promotion of non-staged builds**", and then have a "**Artifactory Release Promotion**" link in the build page to achieve this.

With a pipeline job, I can define a promotion configuration with the artifactory pipeline DSL. But apparently the only thing to to with it, is to call

```
artifactoryServer.promote promotionConfig
```

which triggers immediate promotion.

This doesn't help me, as the promotion should neither happen at build time, nor does it happen on programmable conditions, but only on manual selection.

Is there a way to achieve this for pipeline jobs, just the way it works for freestyle jobs?

Comment: This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/issues/63

Comment: Thank you! Chiming in there.